# How to apply ip lookup using polars?

Tags: python, python-polars, pyarrow

Given two tables I'd like to conduct a lookup over all ips and find the network it belongs to:

I have two large tables:

[image: clients]

and the following networks:

[image: networks]

Regarding the ClientIP (First table) I thought of casting the whole column with `ip_address`

Regarding the second column (second table) I thought of casting the whole column with `ip_network`

Something like this:

```
import ipaddress

network = ipaddress.ip_network('99.96.0.0/13')
ip_obj = ipaddress.ip_address('99.87.29.96')
print(ip_obj in network)
```

and then conduct an apply function, but it is very slow especially for tables with this kind of size.

I noticed in some databases like KQL, there is a built-in support:
[ipv4-lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin)

Is there any kind of builtin support for iplookup in **polars**? or in **pyarrows**?
any suggestions?

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably convert the network table to my own list of binary values to make the lookup easier.  You could even have an index for the first byte.  However, I have to wonder what you possibly hope to learn by mapping 45 million IP addresses like this.  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the network dataframe's `IpCidr` blocks are not overlapping, you could convert the IPv4 addresses to a `pl.Int64` and get the max value within the CIDR block.

A function using only a `pl.Expr` to convert an IPv4 address to `pl.Int64`

```py
import polars as pl

def ip_addr4_int64_expr(ipv4_str_expr: pl.Expr):
    return (
        ipv4_str_expr.str.split(".")
        .list.eval(
            pl.element().cast(pl.Int64)
            * (2 ** (8 * (pl.element().cumcount(reverse=True)))).cast(pl.Int64)
        )
        .list.sum()
    )
```

A range of addresses can be derived from the CIDR's prefix by getting the number of available hosts and adding it to the base IPv4's Int64 representation.

```py
cidr_split_ipv4_expr = pl.col("IpCidr").str.split("/").list.get(0)
cidr_prefix_expr = pl.col("IpCidr").str.split("/").list.get(1).cast(pl.Int64)

ip_cidr_df = ip_cidr_df.with_columns(
    ip_addr4_int64_expr(cidr_split_ipv4_expr).alias("ip_addr4_int64"),
    (
        ip_addr4_int64_expr(cidr_split_ipv4_expr)
        - 1
        + ((2 ** (32 - cidr_prefix_expr)).cast(pl.Int64))
    ).alias("cidr_ip_max"),
)

client_df = client_df.with_columns(
    ip_addr4_int64_expr(pl.col("ClientIP")).alias("ip_addr4_int64"),
)
```

Using a `join_asof`, a range lookup can be done. Then null out values that return above the max IP range.

```py
client_df = (
    client_df.sort("ip_addr4_int64")
    .join_asof(ip_cidr_df.sort("ip_addr4_int64"), on="ip_addr4_int64")
    .select(
        "ClientIP",
        "Timestamp",
        pl.when(pl.col("ip_addr4_int64") <= pl.col("cidr_ip_max"))
        .then(pl.col("Info"))
        .alias("Info"),
    )
)
```

Examples:

```py
ip_cidr_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "IpCidr": [
            "99.96.0.0/13", "99.88.0.0/13", "1.0.136.0/22", "1.0.128.0/21",
            "1.0.0.0/24", "10.0.0.0/8", "127.0.0.0/8", "172.16.0.0/12",
            "192.168.0.0/16",
        ],
        "Info": [
            "ATT-INTERNET4", "ATT-INTERNET4", "TOT-NET TOT Public Company Limit", 
            "TOT-NET TOT Public Company Limit", "CLOUDFLARENET", "The 10.0.0.0/8 Range",
            "The 127.0.0.0/8 Range", "The 172.16.0.0/12 Range", "The 192.168.0.0/16 Range",
        ],
    }
)

client_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timestamp": [
            "2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-01 00:00:00", 
            "2023-06-01 00:00:00", "2023-06-30 23:59:00", "2023-06-30 23:59:00",
            "2023-06-30 23:59:00",
        ],
        "ClientIP": [
            "1.0.0.14", "99.96.1.5", "99.87.29.96", "10.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1", "172.16.0.1", "192.168.0.1",
        ],
    }
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌─────────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ ClientIP    ┆ Timestamp           ┆ Info                     │
│ ---         ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                      │
│ str         ┆ str                 ┆ str                      │
╞═════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 1.0.0.14    ┆ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 ┆ CLOUDFLARENET            │
│ 10.0.0.1    ┆ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 ┆ The 10.0.0.0/8 Range     │
│ 99.87.29.96 ┆ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 ┆ null                     │
│ 99.96.1.5   ┆ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 ┆ ATT-INTERNET4            │
│ 127.0.0.1   ┆ 2023-06-30 23:59:00 ┆ The 127.0.0.0/8 Range    │
│ 172.16.0.1  ┆ 2023-06-30 23:59:00 ┆ The 172.16.0.0/12 Range  │
│ 192.168.0.1 ┆ 2023-06-30 23:59:00 ┆ The 192.168.0.0/16 Range │
└─────────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Note: This answer assumes a dataframe consisting only of IPv4 addresses and no overlapping CIDR blocks in `ip_cidr_df`.
The same logic could be applied by converting IPv6 addresses to a `pl.Struct` consisting of `pl.Int64`.

Comment: This is awesome. One small note, doing things in `list.eval` is relatively slow and since the split in your `ip_addr4_int64_expr` must have 4 items you could write that function as: `def ip_addr4_int64_expr(ipv4_str_expr: pl.Expr):
    ipsplit=ipv4_str_expr.str.split(".")
    return (ipsplit.list.get(0).cast(pl.Int64)*2**(8*3) + 
            ipsplit.list.get(1).cast(pl.Int64)*2**(8*2) +
            ipsplit.list.get(2).cast(pl.Int64)*2**(8*1) +
            ipsplit.list.get(3).cast(pl.Int64)*2)` for slightly better performance.